# how can I retrieve the current GMT date and time in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I understand CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), it returns the current local time, which depends on my session setup...
I could convert it to GMT if I knew my local timezone offset...

Is there a simple way to convert this in UTC/GMT that would not depend on my session settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Snowflake's [CONVERT_TIMEZONE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html) function...

```
SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
;
```

Comment: Ok, I guess I missunderstood what's returned by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().
I did not understand it does include the timezone.

Thanks